# Dojo amd loading cross-domain modules at runtime

Tags: dojo, amd

I want to load Dojo1.9 amd modules from an ad-hoc server on the www, but I won't know from where until runtime (with url params).

In essence, I want to do the equivalent of this:

```
require(['http://www.foo.com/SomeRandomModule'], function( SomeRandomModule ) {
    // use SomeRandomModule
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Quick and dirty way

*Might* have some unexpected quirks when it comes to the module system and relative paths, I haven't used it enough to say:

```
require([ "//host/myext/mod1/mod2.js" ],function(mod2){
    // If current webpage is http:// or https:// or file:// 
    // it tries to use the same protocol
});
```

## Better way

Configure `require()` to treat all modules that start with a certain package name (e.g. `foo`) as coming from a particular URL. From your starter page, something like:

```
<script src="dojo/dojo.js" 
    data-dojo-config="packages:[{name:'myext',location:'//host/js/myext'}], async: 1, >
</script>
```

This lets you vastly improve your first example to:

```
require([ "myext/mod1/mod2" ],function(mod2){

});
```

If you are using a Dojo Bootstrap installation instead, you can avoid touching your `data-dojo-config` and instead put it inside the `run.js` startup file:

```
require({
    baseUrl: '',
    packages: [         
        'dojo',
        'dijit',
        'dojox',            
        'myapp',
        { name: 'myext', location: '//host/js/myext', map: {} }
    ]    
}, [ 'myapp' ]);
```

Comment: Awesome...I didn't know you could reference modules using that // syntax. It works, but chokes when the remote module has dependencies that exist only on the remote server.

I'll go ahead and mark your answer complete, but do you have any thoughts on how to resolve the dependencies of the remote module?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to get transitive dependencies working... Maybe some magic with the `package.json` values? I suspect that even if the cross-domain package has something telling you what packages it needs, it'll only state the name, and it'll still be up to you to tell dojo where to go to get the data for it...